# My app crash when loading other xml layout

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I developed an android app. My app crash when I load another layout like this. I don't know how to explain it!!!! Please give me a keyword or everything to search and debug it!! 
My app can launch and load main activity

logcat

```html
                                                                         [ 03-27 06:37:57.264  1419: 1419 D/         ]
                                                                         HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8073fa8, tid 1419
03-27 06:37:57.272 1419-1419/com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
03-27 06:37:57.272 1419-1419/com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
03-27 06:37:57.336 1419-1419/com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-27 06:37:57.336 1419-1419/com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
03-27 06:37:57.336 1419-1419/com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
03-27 06:37:57.348 1419-1419/com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
03-27 06:37:57.352 1419-1419/com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
03-27 06:37:57.352 1419-1419/com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-27 06:38:00.036 1419-1419/com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion I/Choreographer: Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 06:38:05.540 1419-1419/com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-27 06:38:05.540 1419-1419/com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d5eb20)
03-27 06:38:05.540 1419-1419/com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion, PID: 1419
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion/com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion.DatLichHenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                     at com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion.DatLichHenActivity.intentButton(DatLichHenActivity.java:189)
                                                                                     at com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion.DatLichHenActivity.onCreate(DatLichHenActivity.java:50)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

```html
package com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button buttonDatDichVu;
    Button buttonGioiThieu;
    ImageView imvSuaQuanAo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonDatDichVu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDatDichVu);
        buttonGioiThieu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGioiThieu);
        imvSuaQuanAo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imvSuaQuanAo);
        intentButton();

    }

    protected void openDatDichVu(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, DatLichHenActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    protected void openGioiThieu(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, GioiThieuActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    protected void openSuaQuanAo(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, SuaQuanAoActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    protected void intentButton(){
        buttonDatDichVu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openDatDichVu();
            }
        });
        buttonGioiThieu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGioiThieu();
            }
        });
        imvSuaQuanAo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openSuaQuanAo();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

y layout. 
Thanks so much!

//ps
Nothing in logcat,

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_datlichhen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion.DatLichHenActivity">


    <CheckBox
        android:text="Giặt sấy tận nơi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxGiatUi"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:text="Sửa quần áo tận nơi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxSuaQuanAo"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBoxGiatUi"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBoxGiatUi"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView6" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Tên của bạn"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxGiatUi"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/editTextHoTen"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/hotline"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewGoiNgay"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Đặt lịch hẹn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Bạn muốn sử dụng dịch vụ gì?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Đặt ngay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonDatNgay"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageViewGoiNgay"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Địa chỉ"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        android:id="@+id/edtDiaChi"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextSoDienThoai"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextSoDienThoai"
        android:hint="Số điện thoại"
        tools:maxLength="13"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextHoTen"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Bạn muốn sửa sản phẩm gì?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"

        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnChonLoaiDo"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnChonLoaiDo"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Chọn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnChonLoaiDo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonDatNgay"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
package com.xuanlocfashion.xuanlocfashion;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DatLichHenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CheckBox checkBoxGiatUi;
    CheckBox checkBoxSuaQuanAo;
    EditText editTextHoTen;
    EditText editTextSoDienThoai;
    Button buttonDatNgay;
    ImageView imageViewGoiNgay;
    SmsManager sms;
    String hotlineXuanLocFashion1 = "0908418036";
    String hotlineXuanLocFashion2 = "0936208806";
    String smsMessage;
    Button btnChonLoaiDo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dat_lich_hen);
        AnhXa();
        GuiMessage();
        imageViewGoiNgay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                call();
            }
        });
        intentButton();
    }

    private void GuiMessage() {
        sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsMessage = editTextHoTen.getText().toString() + " " + editTextSoDienThoai.getText().toString() + " " + " ";
        buttonDatNgay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkBoxGiatUi.isChecked()) {
                    smsMessage += "(GU)";
                }
                if (checkBoxSuaQuanAo.isChecked())
                    smsMessage += "(SQA)";
                dialogDatLichHen();
            }
        });
    }
    private void AnhXa() {
        checkBoxGiatUi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxGiatUi);
        checkBoxSuaQuanAo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSuaQuanAo);
        editTextHoTen = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextHoTen);
        editTextSoDienThoai = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSoDienThoai);
        buttonDatNgay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDatNgay);
        imageViewGoiNgay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewGoiNgay);
    }
    protected void call() {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + hotlineXuanLocFashion1));//change the number
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DatLichHenActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DatLichHenActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
    protected void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        // SMS sent

                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        // SMS fail without reason

                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        // No service

                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        // Null PDU

                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        // Radio off

                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        // SMS delivered"

                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        // SMS not delivered

                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
    protected void dialogDatLichHen() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // khởi tạo dialog
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Đặt lịch hẹn ngay.");
        // thiết lập nội dung cho dialog
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Đồng ý", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                sendSMS(hotlineXuanLocFashion1, smsMessage);
                sendSMS(hotlineXuanLocFashion2, smsMessage);

            }
        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Không", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                // button "no" ẩn dialog đi
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        // tạo dialog
        alertDialog.show();
        // hiển thị dialog
    }
    protected void openChonLoaiDo(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ChonLoaiDoActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    protected void intentButton(){
        btnChonLoaiDo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openChonLoaiDo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: watch the stack trace what it says

Comment: Is it out of memory error?

Comment: show your logcat also?

Comment: put Activity java code and stack trace

Comment: @ShubhankGupta I added it.

Comment: @LocLeXuan check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to dry run your code in your `DatLichHenActivity.java` may be you forget to get the view of the  `Button btnChonLoaiDo;` so it generate the null object reference there.

Comment: Thanks!!! It's work. I'm so carelessness.

Comment: @LocLeXuan your welcome